# Xcode can segue from storyboard to xib but not opposite>?

Tags: xcode, storyboard, segue, xib, viewcontroller

I've got a very big problem!

I can segue from storyboard to xib file like this: (image) http://s14.postimg.org/xgq004vsh/screen.png

This is all working fine but this doesn't:

Ok, now i'm in the xib file and want to get back to the main storyboard or just the previous view if that makes a difference..But that is not working at all, it crashes when i do it, look at the image and you can see the log and the code i'm using (the "Back" function): http://s4.postimg.org/wi3myjgjh/screen2.png
 And it crashes everytime! PLEASE TELL ME WHY AND WHAT I CAN DO!

Thanks!! I really appreciate help! :)

Comment: may you please post the code what you tried ?

Comment: the code is in the images @Odedra? Thanks